# Mongoose 1:Many Parent Relation Doesn't Save (says undefined)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am new to `express/mongoose` and trying to implement User-Post relationship.Aka 1:Many.

I have two `models`,

```
 // *models/user.js

 var mongoose = require('mongoose');

 var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
      email: {type: 'string'},
      password: {type: 'string'},
      posts: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post'}]
    });
 module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

// *models/post.js

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  user : { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  body: String,
  title: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);
```

**server.js**,

```
Post = require('./models/post');
User = require('./models/user');

app.post('/api/posts',(req,res)=>{

  User.findOne({email: "valid_email"},(err, user)=>{

    var post = {
      title: "Post 1 Title",
      body: "Post 1 body",
      user: user._id
    }
    Post.create(post, (err, post)=>{
      res.send(post);
   });
  });
});
```

Now, this approach is working for saving the `Post` which belongs to user with email "valid_email".I can reach out it's user by populating.

```
app.get('/post', (req,res)=>{
  Post.findOne(title: "Post 1 title")
 .populate('user')
 .exec(function (err, user) {
   if (err) throw err;
   console.log(user._id, user.email);
   res.end();
 });
});
```

I thought generating a `Post` in the callback of finding a User would automatically push it to User's posts.Not only it is not how it works, i can't push manually to "user.posts".

It says can't "push" to undefined.When i `console.log(user.posts)` i get `undefined`.

How is it that i can generate a Post `belongsTo` a User, then i can populate the user just by it's `id`, but can't push a Post to User? It gives undefined "user.posts" ?

Comment: thank you Ravi Shankar for proper edit

Answer (score 0):

!!! I got it working.

```
app.post('/api/posts', (req,res)=>{
  User.findOne({id: _some_user_id}, (err,user)=>{
    var poster = user;
    var post = {title: req.body.title, body: req.body.body, category: req.body.category, user: poster}
    Post.create(post, (err,post)=>{
      res.send(post);
      poster.posts.push(post);
      poster.save();
    });
  });
});
```